# Email Deep linking(like share) not work to android in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking

i am developing one sample application. In this application getting more options like share options. But Email share option not working but share requirements all getting . In iOS device working fine android not working yet. Please check and give me advice solve my issue.

here this is my Code :

```
    sendEmail () {

    alert(this.state.artifact.link);
    let subject = this.state.artifact.title;
    !subject && (subject = '');

    let body = 'Link: ' + this.state.artifact.link;

    Linking.openURL('mailTo:?subject=' + S(subject).decodeHTMLEntities().s +
        '&body=' + S(body).decodeHTMLEntities().s);
}
```

getting Error like this :
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19061 Maybe it's related to this issue. The shown issue is connected with openTel, but this creator has also issues on android with usinng the mailTo key.